# ¿Por qué mi página web en el servidor local se ve perfecto y cuando la subo al hosting desaparecen los estilos del header?

Tags: html, css, css3, localhost, host

Me está matando esto porque en el local host se ve como me gusta, la subí a internet y desaparece el header.

Por favor ayúdenme.

Asi se ve en local host
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNTXQ.png]

Asi en el host de internet

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Como estás referenciando los archivos css?

Comment: Parece que tienes un problema con las rutas al archivo css, revísalas porque creo que ese es tu problema. Puedes incluir una imagen de la estructura de tus archivos y asi seria mas facil ayudarte.

Comment: También incluye tu código HTML como texto en el cuerpo de la pregunta, apropiadamente formateado por favor

Comment: Te recomiendo hacer tus pruebas locales con firefox, el problema son las rutas de tus archivos css

Comment: Dale en inspeccionar y revisa la consola, ahí te dirá si hay archivos que no fueron encontrado, lo más probable es que alguna ruta esté mal referenciada

Answer (score 0):

no puedo comentar, así que te respondo aquí, revisa las rutas del css, digamos si el css lo tienes dentro de una carpeta css, en html debes poner ./css/styles.css y si esta a nivel del html entonces prueba con ./styles.css